# What comes with Clojure-Mode for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, clojure, key-bindings

I'm aware of of C-h b to look at the Clojure-Mode bindings, but I don't really see anything there that's all that useful.  I use paredit and there are a ton of useful things provided by that mode for editing Clojure, but that stuff is just basic Lisp Parens editing.

When I bring up the bindings for Clojure itself I don't really see must haves.  Aside from syntax highlighting.  I'm thinking I'm missing something.  What does Clojure-Mode provide?

Comment: There are a few phrases in this question that are likely to attract trolls, could you reword the question so that it will be easier to answer definitively.

Answer (score 1):

According to [its GitHub page](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode), Clojure Mode

> Provides Emacs font-lock, indentation, and navigation for the Clojure programming language.

You may want to look into [`CIDER`](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider), which does more:

> `CIDER` (formerly `nrepl.el`) is the Clojure IDE and REPL for Emacs, built on top of [nREPL](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl), the Clojure networked REPL server.

Some specific features:

> - Powerful REPL
> - Interactive code evaluation
> - Compilation notes (error and warning highlighting)
> - Human-friendly stacktraces
> - Smart code completion
> - Definition lookup
> - Documentation lookup
> - Resource lookup
> - Apropos
> - Value inspector
> - Function tracing
> - Interactive macroexpansion
> - [Grimoire](http://conj.io/) integration
> - `clojure.test` integration
> - Classpath browser
> - Namespace browser
> - nREPL session management
> - Scratchpad
> - Minibuffer code evaluation
> - Integration with [company-mode](http://company-mode.github.io/) and [auto-complete-mode](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/ac-cider)

Answer (score 0):

The following link:

"Bozhidar Batsov - The evolution of the Emacs tooling for Clojure" 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4X-1fJm25Ww

gives a good overview of emacs Cider, which is the most popular development environment for clojure developers (at least according to the survey presented by the speaker).

He gives a good overview of what Cider can do, where he wants to take it, and discusses some of the competing environments as well (e.g lightTable, Cursive) .

I picked up on some good pointers on how to more effecitvely use clojure in emacs by watching it.

Bozhidar Batsov is the main developer of emacs Cider.